# what makes a printer a printer in a network?

Tags: networking, printing, network-printer, scanning, nmap

I am scanning a network using nmap. I assume that this network has copy machines and printers with IP addresses. Is there a way I can differentiate the regular computers from the printers? nmap can detect the OS, but is it sufficient?

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: You mean you don't know?  You probably shouldn't be using nmap on someone else's network!

Answer (score 2):

Do a range scan and look for open port 515 and 9100. That will tell you which addresses belong to printers.

```
nmap -p 515,9100 192.168.1.1-200 -oG - | grep open
```

Then check for ports that are "Open". There is an `--open` directive, but it's not working for me, for whatever reason.

515 is also used by print servers, so if you have a domain controller (or whatever) acting as a print server, it'll show up here as well. That's where checking 9100 comes in.

Edit:

You can also just do `nmap -O 192.168.1.1/24 -oG - | grep printer` and trust that nmap will correctly identify the device.

Comment: Add "631" to the interesting ports. IPP printers use 631. LPR/LPD printers use 515. HP JetDirect (or AppSocket) printers very often use 9100 (some also use 4010, 4020, 4030 and 5503).